# Vectorized Splitting of String on Character Count using Numpy or Pandas

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, pandas

Is there a way to split a Numpy Array in a vectorized manner based upon character count for each element?

**Input:**

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: y = np.array([ 'USC00013160194806SNOW','USC00013160194806SNOW','USC00013160194806SNOW' ])

In [3]: y
Out[3]: 
array(['USC00013160194806SNOW', 'USC00013160194806SNOW',
       'USC00013160194806SNOW'], 
      dtype='|S21')
```

I want each element of the array split according to a certain number of characters.

**Desired Output:**

```
In [3]: y
Out[3]: 
array(['USC00013160', 'USC00013160',
       'USC00013160'], 
      dtype='|S21')
```

I've executed this using standard python loops, but I'm dealing with millions of values, so I'm trying to figure the fastest method.

Comment: Are you intentionally asking for the dtype of the desried output to be `'S21'`?  `'S11'` might make more sense.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser no, I'm not specifically looking for a desired output to S21.

Comment: How would you do this in a loop?  `[astr[:11] for astr in a]` or some character search?  `np.char` applies a bunch of `string` functions to elements of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One possible solution** I've found is just completing the operation using Pandas Series, but I'm wondering if this can be done using an ***only Numpy arrays slicing methods***.  If not, it is fine, more curious about the best practice.

**Starting Pandas Series:**

```
In [33]: x = pd.read_csv("data.txt", delimiter='\n', dtype=str, squeeze=True)
In [34]: x
Out[34]: 
0         USC00013160194807SNOW
1         USC00013160194808SNOW
2         USC00013160194809SNOW
3         USC00013160194810SNOW
4         USC00013160194811SNOW, dtype: object
```

**Vectorized String Processing based on Character Count:**

```
In [37]: k = x.str[0:11]
```

**Output:**

```
In [38]: k
Out[38]: 
0         USC00013160
1         USC00013160
2         USC00013160
3         USC00013160
4         USC00013160
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view using a data type with the same size as `y`'s dtype  that has subfields corresponding to the parts that you want.  For example,

```
In [22]: y
Out[22]: 
array(['USC00013160194806SNOW', 'USC00013160194806SNOW',
       'USC00013160194806SNOW'], 
      dtype='|S21')

In [23]: dt = np.dtype([('part1', 'S11'), ('part2', 'S6'), ('part3', 'S4')])

In [24]: v = y.view(dt)

In [25]: v['part1']
Out[25]: 
array(['USC00013160', 'USC00013160', 'USC00013160'], 
      dtype='|S11')

In [26]: v['part2']
Out[26]: 
array(['194806', '194806', '194806'], 
      dtype='|S6')

In [27]: v['part3']
Out[27]: 
array(['SNOW', 'SNOW', 'SNOW'], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

Note that these are all views of the same data in `y`.  If you modify them in place, you are also modifying `y`.  For example,

```
In [32]: v3 = v['part3']

In [33]: v3
Out[33]: 
array(['SNOW', 'SNOW', 'SNOW'], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

Change `v3[1]` to `'RAIN'`:

```
In [34]: v3[1] = 'RAIN'

In [35]: v3
Out[35]: 
array(['SNOW', 'RAIN', 'SNOW'], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

Now see that `y[1]` is also changed:

```
In [36]: y
Out[36]: 
array(['USC00013160194806SNOW', 'USC00013160194806RAIN',
       'USC00013160194806SNOW'], 
      dtype='|S21')
```